# Getting linker error from using tesseract library in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ocr, tesseract

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    string text;
    Mat im;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* ocr = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the error unresolved external symbol in TessBaseAPI. My tesseract should be properly downloaded, in command prompt, "tesseract --version" says I'm using version 5.0, its added to my path. I also tried following this https://github.com/vtempest/tesseract-ocr-sample which didn't work and gave me the linker error.

Comment: are you linking to the tesseract library?

Comment: I followed the steps in the GitHub link adding it as additional dependencies and setting the include directories. It finds the right folder and runs with the headers included but when I try to actually use TessBaseAPI I get the linker error.

Comment: First of all "using namespace std;" is bad programming habit - get rid of it (and it is know to cause conflict in tesseract ;-)). Next post exact error.

Comment: ok, I'll do that for next time. As for my error, I managed to fix the error by installing tesseract through vcpkg. but upon further research the error might have stemmed from me compiling in debug x64 and my tesseract version not being compatible.